# Get value from Object string added using .data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('#test').attr('data-mydata', "{'x-coord': 10}");

var myData = $('#test').data("mydata");
var x = myData['x-coord'];
console.log('x-coord: ' + x);
```

I want to attach to the div above the data noted above.  When the code is executed, the DOM element, #test, is updated with the data which is great.  Then I want to get the data out of the "object".  However, mydata contains a string representation.  How can this string be converted into an object? Bottom line: how can I get the key/value pairs out for further processing? JSON.parse does not seem to work.  Thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/quint/zyozqwv2/

Comment: where does string come from? If you are creating it you can use object as value in data()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> JSON.parse does not seem to work

Well, that’s because it expects *valid* JSON.

`{'x-coord': 10}` isn’t valid JSON – it needs double quotes here, `{"x-coord": 10}`

And as soon as you fix that, you don’t need to parse it yourself any more, `.data()` will do that automatically:

```
$('#test').attr('data-mydata', '{"x-coord": 10}'); // switched quotes here

var myData = $('#test').data("mydata");
var x = myData['x-coord'];
console.log('x-coord: ' + x); // result: x-coord: 10
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zyozqwv2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, something happend wrong with some encoding in your case so pass json object using `JSON.stringify` and parse it using `JSON.parse` method also it is a best practice :)

```js
    $('#test').data('mydata', JSON.stringify({'x-coord': 10}));

    var myData = JSON.parse($('#test').data("mydata"));
    var x = myData['x-coord'];
    console.log('x-coord: ' + x);
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = 'test'></div>
```

Comment: if OP has access to object what is the point of stringifying it?